# Windows shell scripts in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-scripting

I was pretty sure that some months ago I read about the possibility to launch Windows scripts not only the usual `.bat`, but also `.js`, `.vbs` and `.cs` !

I was willing to try windows scripts in C# `.cs` files this morning, but I can't happen to find any references on the web. All CS/C# scripts stuffs seem to be 3rd parties.

Do you have any knowledge reference/link for command-line scripts in C# for Windows, pure microsoft style ?

Yes, that would mean dynamic C# compilation... so maybe I am all wrong thinking it is possible. Just tell me.

Comment: These two hacks are one way: http://www.mvps.org/scripting/dotnet/index.htm, http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84414/scripting-with-c/.  You could also be thinking about powershell (?)

Comment: In this case, the "cs" probably meant CScript, not C#, and it was the name of the shell program, not the language.

Answer (score 7):

#### Option A

If you're looking for a true C# development experience, try [**CS-Script**](http://www.csscript.net/).

You can use comment directives to use third-party libraries and include other C# scripts.

```
//css_nuget dotnetzip
using Ionic.Zip;
using System;

class Script
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddFile("app.exe");
            zip.AddFile("readme.exe");
            zip.Save("app.zip");
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer `CS-Script` because I've noticed **1)** **faster** script *start-up* times compared to `scriptcs` below and **2)** no issues using **namespaces**. C# you write here is real C#. The VS IDE just works.

#### Option B

Alternatively, take a look at **[scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net/)**

http://scriptcs.net/

You can also use VS to write some simple scripts:

```
 //MyScript.Main()

 public class MyScript{
     public static void Main(){
          Console.WriteLine("hello world.");
     }
 }
```

When you're ready to run scripts with `scriptcs`, remove the `//` comment.

`C:\> scriptcs myscript.cs`

Also, you can use nuget to install 3rd party packages like `NLog`

`C:\> scriptcs -install NLog`

One problem I found with `scriptcs` is the inability to use **namespaces**. `scriptcs` under the hood uses the Roslyn compiler for compiling C# scripts. Unfortunately, Roslyn has a leaky design implementation when compiling scripts. In particular, in order for Roslyn to handle REPL type of use cases, each script compilation uses nested classes to store variables and state. Since you can't have a namespace in a nested `class` using **namespaces** with `scriptcs` will fail. So if you try to import loose `*.cs` files that contain namespaces (like domain objects from a VS project), you'll need to strip out the namespaces.

This awful design decision left a bad impression on me, so I've mostly used `cs-script` **Option A** until the Roslyn team supports namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can run scripting through the WSH (Windows Scripting Host):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: +1 but however, it doesnt seem it can do C#... Js, vbs and other language yes... but not C#... unless I mistake...

Comment: No, no C# scripting is available out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution which gives yoyu a lot of power and available commands you might find interesting is `PowerShell` :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419